# Fastest way to computing Checksum and Better Sql Server data-type to save that

Tags: c#, checksum, sql-server-2008-r2

In the my application, i save urls content into specific table of database. to have minimum duplication, i want to compute checksum for each content. so what is best sqlserver data-type for saving checksum's? and fastest way to computing checksum's for contents(html) of urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SHA1](http://dotnetpulse.blogspot.com/2007/12/sha1-hash-calculation-in-c.html) could be used to calculate the checksum. The result is a byte array which could be stored either as hex string or blob field in SQL but I think for practical reasons a string would be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a built in function in sql server to compute any of these( MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, or SHA1)

examples

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', 'http://www.cnn.com')
```

that returns the varbinary datatype 0xC50252F4F24784B5D368926DF781EDE9

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', 'http://www.cnn.com'),2)
```

that returns a varchar C50252F4F24784B5D368926DF781EDE9

Now all you have to do is picking if you want varchar or varbinary and use that for your column

See [Generating a MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, or SHA1 hash by using HashBytes](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Generating_a_MD2,_MD4,_MD5,_SHA,_or_SHA1_hash_by_using_HashBytes)

Comment: OK, this is a good approach. but there is limitation (max length of input is 8000 bytes)